# The authentication demand was rejected because the token had no audience attached

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0, openiddict

I want to authenticate the API resources using **client credentials**.

I have been able to generate the token successfully.

While sending the request for the API I logged the error and it says:

```
2021-06-10T00:47:19.1953056+05:45 [ERR] (OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher) The authentication demand was rejected because the token had no audience attached.
2021-06-10T00:47:19.1954307+05:45 [INF] (OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler) "OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore" was not authenticated. Failure message: "An error occurred while authenticating the current request."
2021-06-10T00:47:19.1960031+05:45 [INF] (OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher) The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: "{
  \"error\": \"invalid_token\",
  \"error_description\": \"The specified token doesn't contain any audience.\",
  \"error_uri\": \"https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2093\"
}".
2021-06-10T00:47:19.1960852+05:45 [INF] (OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler) AuthenticationScheme: "OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore" was challenged.
```

What I am missing in my configuration? what is the correct way of using the client credentials grant type to secure the API resources with openiddict?

**Resource Server Startup Configuration:**

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                });
    services.AddOpenIddict()
       .AddValidation(options =>
       {
           
           options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:44301/");
           options.AddAudiences("signal_system_web_resource");
           options.UseIntrospection()
                 .SetClientId("signal_system_web_resource")
                 .SetClientSecret("846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342");
           options.UseSystemNetHttp();
           options.UseAspNetCore();
       });
    services.AddHttpClient();


    return services;
    }
```

**The Client Configuration:**

```cs
 if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("nj-client") == null)

{
    await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
    {
        ClientId = "nj-client",
        ClientSecret = "C4BBED05-A7C1-4759-99B5-0F84A29F0E08",
        DisplayName = "Ninja Client Application",
        Permissions =
        {
            Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
            Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
        }
    });
}        

if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("signal_system_web_resource") == null)
{
    var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
    {
        ClientId = "signal_system_web_resource",
        ClientSecret = "846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342",
        Permissions =
        {
            Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection
        }
    };

    await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
}
```

**OpenIddictScopeDescriptor**

```cs
var descriptor = new OpenIddictScopeDescriptor
{
    Name = "signal.system.web",
    Resources =
    {
        "signal_system_web_resource"
    }
};
```

**Resource Server API Controller**

```cs
[Authorize]

[HttpGet("message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage()
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (identity == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Content($"Signal System Web says that you have authorized access to resources belonging to {identity.Name}.");
}
```

Please help me through the error. any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever try to add this to your authorization configuration: `options.AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL` to `true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by adding the resources while generating the token.

```cs
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); 
principal.SetResources("signal_system_web_resource");
return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: If you aquire a SPA token and you define scopes in openiddict server, don't forget to request them in SPA app